# Get clicked image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, image

I'm working on a productpage. My goal is to show the clicked image in the upfollowing page. My problem is that I always see the same image, which is the first picture from the array.

The website shows a 6 pictures with different images. The image that is clicked is the one that I want to load on the next 'page'. How can I check which image image was clicked and then send that one into my jQuery HTML element in the loadProduct function(`<img class="img-fluid headerImg mt-5 mb-5" src="CALL CLICKED IMAGE HERE">`)? I guess that's the main thing that I'm running into. I can't find the correct way how to select the image that was clicked. Although it's probably just something quite simple.

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/interactie.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jstest.js"></script>
    <title>Products</title> 
  </head>

  <main>
    <div id="productOverlay">
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row items m-0">
        <div class="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      <div class="mx-3 mb-5 storybutton">
        <a href="ourstory.html">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto">Read our story<i class="button fa fa-angle-double-right ml-2"></i></button>
        </a>
      </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <div class="container">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <div class="row flex-md-row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <li><a class="mx-3" href="#">Terms &amp; Conditions</a></li>
            <li><a class="mx-3" href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
            <li><a class="mx-3" href="#">Return Policy</a></li>
          </div>
          <div class="d-sm-block d-md-none" style="height: 10px; background-color: white; width: 100px; visibility: hidden;"></div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-lg-3">
            <li><a class="mx-3" href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a class="mx-3" href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
            <li><a class="mx-3" href="faq.html">Newsletter</a></li>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ul>
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/theforrestr/">
        <div class="icons mx-3 float-right">
          <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagramIcon">
        </div>
      </a>
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/theforrestr/">
        <div class="icons float-right">
          <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebookIcon">
        </div>
      </a>
    </div>
  </footer>

</html>
```

This is my jQuery/JavaScript:

```
var shirts = [
  {
    "imgFile" : "images/shirt1.png",
    "name" : "Sloth",
    "price" : "25"
  },
  {
    "imgFile" : "images/shirt.png",
    "name" : "Piranha",
    "price" : "35"
  },
  {
    "imgFile" : "images/shirt.png",
    "name" : "Turtle",
    "price" : "15"
  },
  {
    "imgFile" : "images/shirt1.png",
    "name" : "Sloth",
    "price" : "25"
  },
  {
    "imgFile" : "images/shirt.png",
    "name" : "Piranha",
    "price" : "35"
  },
  {
    "imgFile" : "images/shirt.png",
    "name" : "Turtle",
    "price" : "15"
  }
]

$(document).ready(documentReady);

function documentReady()
{
  createItem();
}

function createItem(e){

  for(var i = 0; i < shirts.length; i++)
  {
    var item = $(`<article class="col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
<img class="img-fluid" src=` + shirts[i].imgFile + ` alt="jungleImage">
<h5 class="mt-1">` + shirts[i].name + `</h5>
<h6 class="mt-n2 mb-3">€` + shirts[i].price + `</h6>
</article>`);
    item.find( 'img' ).click( loadProduct );

    $('.items').append(item);
  }
};

function loadProduct(e)
{
  var product = $(`<!-- small screens body --> 
  <main class="d-sm-block d-md-none smallscreen">
    <div class="overlay-size"></div>
    <picture>
      <img class="img-fluid headerImg mt-5 mb-5" src="**CALL CLICKED IMAGE HERE**">
    </picture>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row flex-column m-0">
        <div class="col d-flex flex-column">
          <h2 class="mb-0">Productname</h2>
          <h6 class="m-0">€25,00</h6>
          <hr class="mx-0">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-column m-0">
        <div class="col">
          <h6 class="mb-1">Colour</h6>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="white mr-3"></div>
            <div class="black mr-3"></div>
            <div class="grey"></div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-column m-0">
        <div class="col">
          <h6 class="mb-1">Quantity</h6>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="form-group m-0">
              <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
                <option>1</option>
                <option>2</option>
                <option>3</option>
                <option>4</option>
                <option>5</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row flex-column m-0">
        <div class="row col-12 m-0">
          <h6 class="mb-1" style="flex-grow: 1;">Size</h6>
          <a class="size-chart">
            <h6 class="mb-1"><u><b>size chart</b></u></h6>
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
              <div class="row col-12 m-0 p-0 justify-content-between mb-3">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary size-btn col-3">XS</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary size-btn col-3">S</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary size-btn col-3 active">M</button>
              </div>
              <div class="row col-12 m-0 p-0 justify-content-between">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary size-btn col-3">L</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary size-btn col-3">XL</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary size-btn col-3">XXL</button>
              </div>
              <hr>
            </div>
        <div class="row flex-column m-0">
          <div class="col">
            <h6 class="mb-1">Product Details</h6>
            <ul class="mb-5">
              <li class="product">Made from 100% biological cotton.</li>
              <li class="product">We use 100% eco-friendly paint.</li>
              <li class="product">Available in 3 colours.</li>
              <li class="product">Our packaging is made from recycled cardboard.</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="mb-5">
              <a href="#">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-12 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto">+ Add to cart</button>
              </a>
            </div>     
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>);

  $('#productOverlay').html(product);  
  $('.items').hide();
  $('.storybutton').hide();
    });
  };
```

Comment: Note that since you're already using the backticks, might as well use template literals rather than string concatenation (e.g., `<img class="img-fluid" src="${shrits[i].imgFile}" alt="jungleImage">`).

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I'm quite new to this site and don't really know how to format text the right way

Comment: Nothing to do with the site. It's a feature of JavaScript. See MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your `img` elements in a parent `div` that will server as an event delegation container. This way, you only need to set up a single event handler in your code (instead of one on each and every `img`). Something like this:

```js
const handleImgClick = e => {
  /**
    Do whatever you want with the clicked element in this function. e is an argument provided to your handler function by the browser and contains lots of information regarding the event you're listening for. For this example I am simply loggin the img that was clicked.
    */
  if (e.target.tagName === 'IMG') {
    loadProduct(e.target.alt)
  }
};

const loadProduct = product => {
  console.log(`Executing loadProduct(${product})..`);
};

document.querySelector('#image-container').addEventListener('click', handleImgClick);
```

```html
<!-- Wrap all your images in a parent container, so we can delegate all the event listening to a single DOM element -->
<div id="image-container">
  <img src="images/instagram.svg" alt="instagramIcon">
  <img src="images/facebook.svg" alt="facebookIcon">
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get an error on the 'target'. And how can I add the clicked image into my HTML jQuery element?

Comment: What error? The `target` is a reference to the object that dispatched the event.

Answer (score 0):

Your JS is ugly. To persist the image, you can add a data attribute with the name or path like: `<img class="img-fluid" src="..." data-name="image.png">` and then you listen the click event on it:

```
$(".img-fluid").on('click', function(e){
  var self = $(this);
  var name = self.data('name'); // or src = self.attr('src');
  localStorage.setItem('the-img', name or src);
});
```

and from the other page, you get the image name or path from `var name = localStorage.getItem('the-img')`
`<img src='/folder/'+name+'.png'>`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Well I'm sorry. This is all new to me, so I'm already glad when it works. But I can't get this to work :(..

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Where are you getting the shirts object? Why aren't you using a server side language? Have you tried my snippet?